# Can not access copied filesin var/www ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, localhost

I'm on Ubuntu 14.10 .
I copied a subdirectory which has project files (php, html, css) from **xampp/htdocs** on my Windows PC into **/var/www/** of my ubuntu.
However, when I access those files from browser (I can not see the directory listing), I get `402 Object not found`. Hence that, I installed `Apache2`,`mysql 5.5` and `phpmyadmin` and also conducted update apt-get update for the system and I granted chmod-R 777 access to `/var/www`.
Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: If you use  mod_rewrite of apache then you have to check if [mod_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5758551/2151290) is on

Answer (score 0):

You must put the files on `/var/www/html`
Then try `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html`